# Global Styles In Chakra UI

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

For some reason height:100% doesn't work. Can someone help me

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  fonts: {
    body: "Poppins",
  },
  styles: {
    global: {
      "html, body": {
        height: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "gray.50",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`100%` will not work in this case, but `100vh` might do trick though.

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  fonts: {
    body: "Poppins",
  },
  styles: {
    global: {
      "html, body": {
        height: "100vh",
        backgroundColor: "gray.50",
      },
    },
  },
});
```